# Ajax call while some code is executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a pice of code that looks like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: './something.jsp',
        data : i,
        success: function(data) {
        ...
        }
     });
}
```

The 'for' statement is executing for some time and while is executing I cannot execute another ajax call.

What is the best practice for something like that and what can I do to execute another ajax call while my 'for' statement is executing?

Comment: It will already do what you are asking for it to do. The for loop will run to completion, fireing off `n` requests one after the other, with no delay inbetween and without waiting for each one to complete. Once the for loop is complete, the code after will run, while waiting for the ajax requests to complete.

Comment: The question really is, what are you actually trying to do? Where is this "other" ajax call?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to execute 1 to n ajax calls simultaneously. Might want to read https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/ .

Comment: I have a javascript with multiple functions and multiple calls. While that 'for' is executing I cannot do anything. I understand why I cannot do anything else but I need to find out a solution for this

Comment: Your code (at least the one in the question) does exactly what you're asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/3mjayn1e/

Comment: How many parallel Ajax calls are you running with that loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are asking is something a long the lines of multi-threading which Javascript doesnt have.

I.e.

StartNewThread(AjaxLoop)

mainThread:DoMoreStuffEvenIfAjaxLoopIsntComplete()

The nearest I think you can get to this though I havnt used it myself is with Web Workers http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp though this is really for newer browsers.